# Not getting value in Jsonata output

Tags: json, jsonata

My Json response looks like this and I am trying to get the values for custom_activity.actitype_1AC8KLe2XghWuNlO93LMv5.count inside data object for each date.

My jsonata query is

```
data. {
    "value": custom_activity.actitype_1AC8KLe2XghWuNlO93LMv5.count,
    "date": datetime
}
```

I know the reason why this is happening is because of the "." inside the custom_activity.actitype_1AC8KLe2XghWuNlO93LMv5.count. But I can't change it as it belongs to a third party and I have no control over that.
So I am unable to find a way around this to get the values using jsonata.

It works when i remove the dots in the custom_activity.actitype_1AC8KLe2XghWuNlO93LMv5.count object. So the dots are the reason why this is happening.

```
{
    "aggregations": {
        "totals": {
            "custom_activity.actitype_1AC8KLe2XghWuNlO93LMv5.count": 87,
            "custom_activity.actitype_3hhepbDK50KhtrV9cnLTiN.count": 103,
            "custom_activity.actitype_3s8V7iv8ka6zFii5KVr8oF.count": 265,
            "custom_activity.actitype_3xec3f7Z3tP8fRo6l8mh00.count": 88,
            "custom_activity.actitype_4izlAyTeClOO50BLjHHC9F.count": 328,
            "custom_activity.actitype_4nTymVIz4li2swFSUIQCjB.count": 70,
            "custom_activity.actitype_6sq5Xno7A5Oi7zWimxWSdx.count": 39
        }
    },
    "data": [{
        "custom_activity.actitype_1AC8KLe2XghWuNlO93LMv5.count": 0,
        "custom_activity.actitype_3hhepbDK50KhtrV9cnLTiN.count": 0,
        "custom_activity.actitype_3s8V7iv8ka6zFii5KVr8oF.count": 7,
        "custom_activity.actitype_3xec3f7Z3tP8fRo6l8mh00.count": 0,
        "custom_activity.actitype_4izlAyTeClOO50BLjHHC9F.count": 11,
        "custom_activity.actitype_4nTymVIz4li2swFSUIQCjB.count": 0,
        "custom_activity.actitype_6sq5Xno7A5Oi7zWimxWSdx.count": 0,
        "datetime": "2024-01-01T00:00:00+00:00"
    }, {
        "custom_activity.actitype_1AC8KLe2XghWuNlO93LMv5.count": 3,
        "custom_activity.actitype_3hhepbDK50KhtrV9cnLTiN.count": 3,
        "custom_activity.actitype_3s8V7iv8ka6zFii5KVr8oF.count": 34,
        "custom_activity.actitype_3xec3f7Z3tP8fRo6l8mh00.count": 3,
        "custom_activity.actitype_4izlAyTeClOO50BLjHHC9F.count": 27,
        "custom_activity.actitype_4nTymVIz4li2swFSUIQCjB.count": 0,
        "custom_activity.actitype_6sq5Xno7A5Oi7zWimxWSdx.count": 0,
        "datetime": "2024-01-02T00:00:00+00:00"
    }, {
        "custom_activity.actitype_1AC8KLe2XghWuNlO93LMv5.count": 10,
        "custom_activity.actitype_3hhepbDK50KhtrV9cnLTiN.count": 5,
        "custom_activity.actitype_3s8V7iv8ka6zFii5KVr8oF.count": 12,
        "custom_activity.actitype_3xec3f7Z3tP8fRo6l8mh00.count": 3,
        "custom_activity.actitype_4izlAyTeClOO50BLjHHC9F.count": 20,
        "custom_activity.actitype_4nTymVIz4li2swFSUIQCjB.count": 6,
        "custom_activity.actitype_6sq5Xno7A5Oi7zWimxWSdx.count": 2,
        "datetime": "2024-01-03T00:00:00+00:00"
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your path for the `value` property in backticks, that way JSONata will consider it a single path segment and work as expected:

```
data.{
  "value": `custom_activity.actitype_1AC8KLe2XghWuNlO93LMv5.count`,
  "date": datetime
}
```

Check it out live on the Stedi Playground: https://stedi.link/CTr8rLv